# Problema con Select encadenado con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo un problema de logica con jquery, debido a que tengo un codigo con selects encadenados, en el cual se supone que un submit **se activa solo cuando los tres selects estan activos**, el primer select activa el segundo, y el segundo select activa el tercer select, y si se desactiva el segundo select, se desactiva el tercer select, y si se desactiva el primer select, se desactivan todos.

Pero en mi caso, cuando todos los selects estan activos, se activa el submit, **pero si desactivo el segundo select, no desactiva el boton de submit**

Aqui esta el codigo.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1 class="page-header">jQuery Chained Select</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <form action="" id="addToCart">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select name="color" id="size" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Size</option>
            <option value="Small">Small</option>
            <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="Large">Large</option>
            <option value="X-Large">X-Large</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <select name="color" id="color" class="form-control" disabled>
            <option value="">Color</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="Green">Green</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <select name="qty" id="qty" class="form-control" disabled>
            <option value="">Quantity</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default" disabled><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
function chainSelect(current, target){
  var value1 = $(current).on('change', function(){
    if($(this).find(':selected').val() != ''){
      $(target).removeAttr('disabled');
      var value = $(this).find(':selected').text();
    }else{
      $(target).prop('disabled', 'disabled').val(null);
    }
  return value;
  });
  return value1;
}
size = chainSelect('select#size', '#color');
color = chainSelect('select#color', '#qty');
qty = chainSelect('select#qty', '#submit');

$('#addToCart').submit(function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('Size: ' + size + '\nColor: ' + color + '\nQuantity: ' + qty);
});
```

[Este es el enlace del codigo](http://codepen.io/CSWApps/pen/Bemst)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que estás referenciando los id de cada elemento: `#size, #color, #qty, #submit`, una solución ultrarápida es desactivar el botón submit cuando se desactive cualquiera de los otros tres elementos, simplement agregándolo al selector en el else, aunque para ser sincero, hay soluciones mucho mejores que esta:

EDICIÓN: deshabilitar todos los select/botones "siguientes" al que sea "deseleccionado".

```js
function chainSelect(current, target){
  var value1 = $(current).on('change', function(){
    if($(this).find(':selected').val() != '') {
      $(target).removeAttr('disabled');
      var value = $(this).find(':selected').text();
    } else {
      $(current).parent().nextAll().find('select, button').prop('disabled', 'disabled').val(null);
    }
  return value;
  });
  return value1;
}
size = chainSelect('#size', '#color');
color = chainSelect('#color', '#qty');
qty = chainSelect('#qty', '#submit');

$('#addToCart').submit(function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('Size: ' + size + '\nColor: ' + color + '\nQuantity: ' + qty);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1 class="page-header">jQuery Chained Select</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <form action="" id="addToCart">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select name="color" id="size" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Size</option>
            <option value="Small">Small</option>
            <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="Large">Large</option>
            <option value="X-Large">X-Large</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <select name="color" id="color" class="form-control" disabled>
            <option value="">Color</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="Green">Green</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <select name="qty" id="qty" class="form-control" disabled>
            <option value="">Quantity</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default" disabled><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok, solo que el detalle que falta es que cuando se quite el primer select con todos los select llenos, se reinicien todos los select, pero es una excelente respuesta.

Comment: Mira la edición que hice.

Comment: Ahora si esta perfecto, gracias, es que no conocia la propiedad nextAll(), gracias.

Comment: De hecho no es una propiedad, es un método ;)

Comment: Cierto, gracias de todos modos